# Why is nagios sending multiple Recovery notifications?

Tags: nagios

Since I updated Nagios Core to version 4.4.0 it is constantly (every 5 minutes) sending recovery notifications for all hosts (HOST UP).

This could even be normal behavior, but the hosts are not getting DOWN so there should be no RECOVERY notification.

Already tried to search for clues but no one seems to have this issue.

Can you help me here?

Comment: This is... not the default behavior.  Is it possible that your Nagios server is somehow losing state?

Comment: Without seeing more information than the version you're running, any answer would just be speculation.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I'm already in contact with Nagios CTO so he can help me here.